# MongoDB skips too much documents (pagination)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

everyone!
I have an issue with MongoDB driver on Nodejs.
I have a component on front-end with pagination which selects some amount of documents from a backend(default is 10 docs). So there is the next code on my backend:

```
  const itemsPerPage = req.body.per_page;
  const currentPage = req.body.current_page;
  let skip = math.eval((currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage);

   let transactions = await collection.find({})
    .sort(sortParam)
    // .collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
    .project({
      "date": 1,
      "from": 1,
      "to": 1,
      "hash": 1,
      "val": 1
    })
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(itemsPerPage)
    .toArray(); // in sort 1 for asc and -1 for desc
    console.log('skip: ' + skip);
    console.log('limit: ' + itemsPerPage);
```

The problem is when I trying to get "the last page" on the component, mongo throws me an empty array. And if I try to get the previous page it gives me exactly last page, sometimes when I use a similar collection with the same model, it throws me empty array on the page before the last page too. So it seems like the problem is not in frontend or backend code, its like problem with mongo. BUT when I paste exactly the same query into Studio3T or Robomongo it works fine. Please help, I'm really confused.
I have almost the same code for another very similar component which works with another collection and there is everything OK.

Comment: How do you know what's the last page ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar By the number of collection documents. Actually its resolved, cuz I had count docs amount from other DB...Any way thank you for paying attention!